# AWS RDS free tier database wont start

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I created a free tier RDS Postgres database in AWS yesterday. It was working fine and I used it probably for 2 hrs. I stopped it after using it. Today when I try to start it, it won't start and also won't give any errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the status of the database? Can you show us a screenshot?

Comment: The status of the RDS is "stopped"

Comment: After you try to Start it, is there anything showing in the "Events" (at the bottom of the side RDS menu)?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to check what is RDS status. If the policy is set for terminate on shutdown, you won't be able to start it.

Comment: This is only on ec2. terminate vs stop is always explicit in RDS.

Comment: The status of the RDS is "stopped"

Comment: It sounds more conversational than an answer. You could use comment section for it.